# Is Ground Glass (still) illegal in Arizona?

Tags: criminal-law, arizona, drugs

I was watching Hamilton's Pharmacopeia and on Season 2, Episode 4, it is claimed that Ground Glass is illegal in Arizona.

I tried to do some digging to confirm or falsify that, but the earliest mentions to anything related is from 3+ years ago, and not really well defined, talking about the amount a person would have being a subjective metric for if or not it would be considered illegal.

[One of the best sources on this is actually from law.stackexchange, but again, might be outdated](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/37450/arizona-laws-regarding-ownership-of-ground-glassware-for-chemistry-usage)

Also, I think laws related to at least Marijuana have changed since then. So I would like to know if this was ever really a thing, and if it is still a thing.

Comment: Asked and answered.

Comment: The fact that it was answered 3 years ago doesn't invalidate the answer.

Comment: Nevermind the fact that asking if a law is still in effect should be entirely permitted, within reasonable margin (3 years, and multiple drug-related laws being changed, should be plenty reasonable margin). --- Fun fact: Laws change.